# Error when trying to print a REF CURSOR variable in Oracle using DataGrip, but works in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c, datagrip

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in Oracle 19c using DataGrip as my SQL client. The stored procedure returns a result set using a REF CURSOR output parameter. Strangely, the code works perfectly fine when executed in Oracle SQL*Plus application, but I encounter an error when running it in DataGrip.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transactionlists(
    p_customer_id IN customers.customer_id%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_transaction_type IN transactions.transactions_type%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_result FOR
        SELECT t.transaction_id, t.transactions_date, t.transactions_type, t.amount,
               c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.phone_number
        FROM transactions t
        JOIN customers c ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
        WHERE (p_customer_id IS NULL OR c.customer_id = p_customer_id)
          AND (p_transaction_type IS NULL OR t.transactions_type = p_transaction_type);
END;
```

And I am trying to execute it and print the result set using the following code in DataGrip:

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR;
EXEC transactionlists(p_result => :rc);
PRINT rc;
```

When i run above code, than i parameter popup windows open and ask for input, but i don't know what to enter in parameter. i attach screenshot of that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaiSl.png).

However, if i enter "rc" in parameter windows and than I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

However, it is worth noting that when I run the same code in Oracle SQL*Plus application, it works perfectly fine, and I can see the result set.

I believe the issue is with the PRINT statement in DataGrip, but I'm not sure how to properly retrieve and display the result set in DataGrip. Can someone please help me understand how to correctly print the result set from a REF CURSOR variable in Oracle using DataGrip?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have this issue reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-625/Run-routine-with-output-parametersoutput-parameters-ref-cursors). To stay updated on the progress, please follow the ticket.